# StackView like gallery in android

Tags: android, stackview

I want to create view like stack-view as shown in below image.Can any buddy know that how to implement this type of custom gallery view ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. Can you give me any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is library who can give something like date
https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView

[image]

**NB:** i see the post is quite old if you got the desired, please share it with us all.